# Codeigniter version 2.0.2 redirect loop issue

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have moved from codeigniter 1.7 to 2.0 and so i replaced MY_Controller to CI_Controller and `parent::MY_Controller();` to `parent::__construct();` in login controller and from login controller view is loading and in that view I have added exit at start of the file its not a problem occurring due to other files.

Now, by this change my error for controller has gone, but the issue is I am having error for redirect loop.

If I have added exit before `parent::__construct();` then it is working fine,but If i have added exit after `parent::__construct();`,its going to redirect loop.

There is nothing writter in my hook.php

```
My route php is 

$route['default_controller'] = "login";
$route["404_override"] = "";

 Codigniter version is 2.0.2

 LOGIN FILE ::


  /public_html/projectname/application/controller/login.php

 class Login extends CI_Controller
 {     

 function __construct()
```

{
       echo "test";exit // Here,its working fine without going to loop

```
   parent::__construct();

    echo "test";exit // Here this will give redirect loop issue 

}
```

}

```
/public_html/projectname/.htaccess

 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]


 // route.php


 $route['default_controller'] = "login";
 $route["404_override"] = "";
```

Comment: Check inside `MY_Controller` file.

Comment: It is inside libraries folder and I have changes it now :

from 

class MY_Controller extends Controller 

to

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller

and from

 parent::Controller();

to 

parent::__construct();

same error.

Comment: Can you share us the file or part of header and login?

Comment: /public_html/projectname/application/controller/login.php

class Login extends CI_Controller
{

function __construct()
{
 echo "test";exit // Here,its working fine without going to loop
    
 parent::__construct();
    
    echo "test";exit // Here this will give redirect loop issue 

}

}

Comment: /public_html/projectname/.htaccess

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: // route.php


$route['default_controller'] = "login";
$route["404_override"] = "";

Comment: Let me know any other files you need?

Comment: Please update the question, i cant read from comments ;)

Comment: Updated it now .....

Login file break in between

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72816/discussion-between-lerry-and-bora).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your server shared or dedicated ?

If it is shared,then make sure that mod_rewrite is enabled on server otherwise it won't recognize htaccess file you have added and that may be the reason for redirect loop issue.

Please ask your hosting provider to make it enable (If it is disabled on shared server) and check !!